# Windows 10 BackgroundMediaPlayer SystemTransportControls Pause Button Not Working

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, background-audio

I have recently decided to add Background Audio playback support for podcasts in my app. I have got most of it to work but, the pause button in the SystemTransportControls of the BackgroundMediaPlayer doesn't seem to do anything.

Here is my background audio task class file:

```
public sealed class AudioPlayer : IBackgroundTask
{
    private BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
    public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        var control = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
        control.IsEnabled = true;
        control.IsPauseEnabled = true;
        control.IsPlayEnabled = true;
        control.IsNextEnabled = false;
        control.IsPreviousEnabled = false;

        taskInstance.Canceled += TaskInstance_Canceled;

        BackgroundMediaPlayer.MessageReceivedFromForeground += BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromForeground;
    }

    private void TaskInstance_Canceled(IBackgroundTaskInstance sender, BackgroundTaskCancellationReason reason)
    {
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Shutdown();
        _deferral.Complete();
    }

    void BackgroundMediaPlayer_MessageReceivedFromForeground(object sender, MediaPlayerDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        object obj;
        e.Data.TryGetValue("MessageBody", out obj);

        string url = (string)obj;
        url = url.Replace("\"", "");
        var source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));

        var list = new MediaPlaybackList();
        list.Items.Add(new MediaPlaybackItem(source));

        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Source = list;
        BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.Play();
    }
}
```

It is important to note that the audio does start playing in the background but I don't have the ability to pause the audio.

Thanks,
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To react to SystemMediaTransportControls (SMTC) and handle each Universal Volume Control (UVC) button: play, pause, next, and previous, we need handle the  [SystemMediaTransportControls.ButtonPressed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.systemmediatransportcontrols.buttonpressed) in `Run` method like following:

```
public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var control = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current.SystemMediaTransportControls;
    control.ButtonPressed += control_ButtonPressed;
    ...
}
```

And in `control_ButtonPressed` method, deal with different buttons like:

```
private void control_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.Button)
    {
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
            //Todo with play
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
            //Todo with pause
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Next:
            //Todo with skip to next;
            break;
        case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Previous:
            //Todo with skip to previous;
            break;
    }
}
```

For a complete sample, please refer to the official [Background audio sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio) on GitHub, especially the [MyBackgroundAudioTask class](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BackgroundAudio/cs/BackgroundAudioTask/MyBackgroundAudioTask.cs). And there is also a very nice post that will walk you through setting up background audio, reacting to device media controls, communicating with the background media player, and managing playlists. Read more at [The Basics of Background Audio](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/01/13/the-basics-of-background-audio/).